# Navigate to storyboard from a viewController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, navigation, storyboard

in my iOS application, I would like to navigate programmatically to a whole storyboard (tabBarController) from a viewcontroller.
I found this solution:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SMShopViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

but it is not what I need, I want to show directly my tabBarController

thank you for your reply

Comment: Your question is not clear or understood by any one, ask exactly what you facing and what you have done.

Comment: tab bar already have embed segue connected to navigate, then what else you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand, You have `UITabBarController` on storyboard like this [image] and you want show it from code?

---

So, Firstly set `storyboard identifier` for `UITabBarController`

---

[image]

---

Then in code

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"KITTabBarController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:NO];
```

If you have parent navigation controller better way to do it is:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[tabBar] animated:YES];
```